# IE7 navigation menu formatting issues - help please

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to make a very simple website for someone (not for money), but I can't get the navigation menus to work in IE7. This is based off of a template.

Shows up correctly in IE8 / chrome.

In IE7, first navigation menu item shows up, then nothing else.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

style.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #0048B3 url(images/img01.png) repeat;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #626262;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #7D7764;
} 

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}   

h2 {
    font-size: 2.8em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

p, ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 180%;
} 

ul, ol {
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #731F1F;
}

a:hover {
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/img02.png) repeat-x left top;
}  

.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}    

/* Header */

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 600px;
}    

#header {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 620px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat right top;
}

/* Logo */

#logo {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}    

#logo h1, #logo p {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #5E8CC3;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}    

#logo h1 {
    padding: 200px 0px 0px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 100px;
}    

#logo p {
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;

    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #B8D1EE;
}

#logo p a {
    color: #696969;
}    

#logo a {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}    

/* Menu */

#menu-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 80px;
}    

#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 80px;
    background: url(images/img03.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}    

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}    

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #64DAFE;
}    

#menu a {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
    background: url(images/img06.png) repeat-x left top;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}    

#menu .current_page_item a {
}

/* Page */

#page {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0px 40px 0px;
}    

/* Content */

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}    

#content h2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #262626;
}    

/* Sidebar */

#sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 256px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #787878;
}

#sidebar1 h2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #262626;
}    



/* Three Column Footer Content */


#footer-bg {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0px;
}    

#footer-content {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #003E93;
    color: #67C8E3;
}    

#footer-content h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}    

#footer-content a {
    color: #56C8E3;
}    

#footer-content a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}    


#column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}    

#column1 p {
    line-height: 1;
}

#column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}    

#column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}

#column4 {
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
}    


/* Footer */

#footer {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/img04.png) no-repeat center top;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #C59C9C;
}

#footer a {
    color: #C59C9C;
}    

#marketing {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}

#marketing .text1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #345E9B;
}

#marketing .text2 {
    float: right;
}

#marketing .text2 a {
    display: block;
    width: 252px;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/img07.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.box1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}    

.list-style1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}    

.list-style1 li {
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #E7E2DC;
}    

.list-style1 .first {
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-top: none;
}    

.list-style2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}    

.list-style2 li {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}    

.list-style2 a {
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url(images/img10.png) no-repeat left 50%;
    color: #717171;
}    

.list-style2 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #606060;
}    

.list-style2 .first {
    padding-top: 0px;
    border: none;
}    

.list-style3 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}    

.list-style3 li {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background: url(images/img12.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}    

.list-style3 a {
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url(images/img13.jpg) no-repeat left 50%;
    color: #717171;
}    

.list-style3 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #606060;
}    

.list-style3 .first {
    padding-top: 0px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}    


/* Three Column Content */

#four-column {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
    color: #626262;
}    

#four-column #tbox1 {
    float: left;
    width: 282px;
    margin-right: 24px;
}    

#four-column #tbox2 {
    float: left;
    width: 282px;
    margin-right: 24px;
}

#four-column #tbox3 {
    float: left;
    width: 282px;
}    

#four-column #tbox4 {
    float: right;
    width: 282px;
}    

.box-style {
    background: #191919 url(images/img05.jpg) repeat;    
}    

.box-style h2 {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #515151;
}    

.box-style .image {
    width: 320px;
}

.box-style .arrow {
    background: url(images/img06.png) no-repeat right top;
}    

.box-style .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px;
}    


.divider {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(images/img04.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--
Design by Free CSS Templates
http://www.freecsstemplates.org
Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License

Name       : Open-Air
Description: A two-column, fixed-width design with dark color scheme.
Version    : 1.0
Released   : 20120818

-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="210 Social Club" />
<meta name="description" content="210 Social Club" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>210 Social Club</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
        <div id="menu" class="container">
            <ul>
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="Newsletter/newsletter.htm">Newsletter</a></li>
                <li><a href="piwigo/">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="private/contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo" class="container">
            <h1><a href="#">210 Social Club</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page" class="container">
        <div id="content">
            <h2 align=center>Welcome to the 210 Social Club webpage.</h2>
            <h2 align=center>Club Purpose:</h2>
            <div class="entry">
                <H3><p>The following is the purpose for which the club has been organized: To create, foster and cultivate a fraternally cooperative spirit among it's members so as to further true and sincere friendship in all it's aspects; to encourage and stimulate interest for the help of our fellow man and the pure social enjoyment for the members and their families; to include physical and athletic recreation for all.</p></H3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #content -->
        <div id="sidebar1">
            <div>
                <img src="images/img11.jpg" alt="club logo"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #sidebar -->
    </div>
    <!-- end #page -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried either giving #menu 100% width, or removing 'overflow: hidden'? Not sure why you'd need to hide the overflow (I know you mentioned this is based off a template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably with inline-block. Try replacing this:

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #64DAFE;
}
```

With this:

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #64DAFE;
}
```

References:

- [IE7 inline-block problem](http://uncorkedstudios.com/2011/12/12/how-to-fix-the-ie7-and-inline-block-css-bug/)
- [forcing layout with zoom](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout)
- [targeting different versions of IE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)